# How to tell Search Engine, that some words are irrelevant?

Tags: seo, keywords

I am developing Photopea, which should be an image editor for users, who need to edit PSD and can not use Photoshop for some reason.

My `index.html` is very short, the only SEO-relevant parts are title, meta keywords and meta description. After `index.html` is loaded, JavaScript adds a lot of new elements with a huge HTML structure.

Here are content keywords from Google search console:
[image]

The words like "server", "color" or "data" occur only as variable names in JS, or in labels of buttons. The "light" occurs in the names of blend modes - "soft light", "hard light", "linear light", "vivid light" ... I doubt, that people looking for image editor would get to my site through "light" keyword.

Is there any convenient way to tell the Search Engine, that some words are completely irrelevant? So it can give more relevance to the other words?

Comment: Mainly just a frequency count of the terms, doesnt mean you will rank for them, or will not. See here https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq--webmaster-tools#strange-words2

Comment: Agreed. The list from Google Search Console is seriously misleading and should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

When website has no more content (like only 20 webpages), then webmaster should not concentrate on this thing.

It contain keywords that Google found on your website, it gives you hint that you're using this type of keywords in your website and there are some variant for particular keyword which you're using.

[It does not represent any relevancy.](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-content-keywords-relevance-15882.html)

I look out on this, to check, Is there any spammy keywords are injected by hacker or not?

Comment: Looking for accidental or spammy terms is all this list is useful for. +1 for the reference! I am not sure why this page even exists. It is fueling a poor notion of how a site does/should perform and why.

Comment: All keywords from the list occur in my webpage somewhere, but they are button labels and there are hundreds of buttons in a complex app such as mine. Ok, I will just ignore this list from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a blank page that gets filled up by JavaScript, you can put a descriptive ad for your app into the HTML body, then replace that when your app loads. There are many advantages:

- specifically to your point, Google will index the ad content, thereby giving you control of what keywords users can search for, e.g. “Photopea enables you to edit PSD images in your Web browser” will be indexed even if that doesn’t show in your JavaScript app
- humans who hit your page with JavaScript off will see an ad for your app instead of a blank page — this includes users who only whitelist JavaScript on a site by site basis and you need to convince them to whitelist you
- your page will validate
- your page will be accessible.

Comment: I think Google is analyzing HTML structure after the page is loaded + Javascript is executed. I have noticed it also from my other sites.